# What, and why, does GNU gettext send over the public internet?

Tags: gettext, privacy

I was trying out gettext and ran `msginit --locale=en --input=messages.po` and this is what I see:

```
[... blah ...]
Is the following your email address?
  localUserName@localHostName
Please confirm by pressing Return, or enter your email address.

Retrieving http://translationproject.org/team/index.html... done.
A translation team for your language (en) does not exist yet.
If you want to create a new translation team for en or en_PG, please visit
  http://www.iro.umontreal.ca/contrib/po/HTML/teams.html
  http://www.iro.umontreal.ca/contrib/po/HTML/leaders.html
  http://www.iro.umontreal.ca/contrib/po/HTML/index.html

Created en_PG.po.
```

What was or would have been disclosed? What is the purpose of this disclosure?

```
$ msginit --version
msginit (GNU gettext-tools) 0.19.8.1
```

Comment: Why do you think it's trying to disclose something?

Comment: @figl, not really related to your question: You should use your `PROJECT.pot` file as input to `msginit`, not a language file (`message.po`). The po template files (pot) contain just the translatable strings for your project without any translation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `wireshark` for tracing here. A text editor will do:

The tool msginit invokes a shell script `<prefix>/share/gettext/projects/TP/team-address` that tries to download (via `<prefix>/lib/gettext/urlget`) the table with translation teams from http://translationproject.org/team/index.html, and it falls back to a local copy installed under `<prefix>/share/gettext/projects/TP/teams.html`.  The purpose of this is to fill the PO header `Language-Team` with an up-to-date email address.

I agree that the user should at least be prompted before an internet connection is opened.

I have opened an upstream issues for that:

- https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/index.php?57847

In versions before 0.20, the program (it is the above-mentioned script `team-address`) always reports that a "translation team for your language (xy) does not exist yet", no matter what locale you specify. This is fixed in gettext version 0.20.1.

Thanks for pointing this out!

As a workaround, you may edit the shell script `team-address` to not invoke `urlget` but use the local copy directly.